# Using a Brushed HTML Template

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

I have done all the personalizing on this template now, being not too familar to code. But it also has a modenizr.js attached, which adds an animated loading screen before opening the site. My problem is I don't want the screen to be there as it doesn't disappear after page is loaded just sits ontop of my site.

Any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks DamianL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you complete your question with some link, and even explaining what you have done to this template please?

Anyway i can suggest you to open the "developer tools" (usually pressing f12) and using the inspector trying to figure out wich is the element that doesn't disappear, and maybe also why.

Im sorry, this is not a real answer, but i don't have enough reputation to just add a comment asking for more info.

Comment: Do you mean a link to the website ? And thankyou but I wouldn't know what i was looking for in the developer tools.

Comment: And all I have done is edit the text and images. That's all I could figure out.

Comment: Yes, a link to your website, or the online template..
Something that can be useful to let us understand wich is the problem.